# Store data after uninstall app

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

This question might be similar to other questions on stack about this problem but none of them helped me. I decided to ask a new one with easy question:

Is is a possible to backup data(JSON file) on iOS and retrieve it after reinstall app?

- I heard about new File app in iOS11. Could it help?
- Maybe iCloud storage? How?
- I checked how to use KeyChain but I realized my data is too big.

I know I can use 3rd part app (for example GoogleDoc) and use their API to store my data. But before I do it I want to be sure there is no chance to do it without them.

Comment: i think u have to get backup from the user every month or week so its data will be store into your server and last update will be conduct as a final backup of user

Answer (score 0):

Since UserDefaults are also uninstalled with application, you can go with iCloud Api and I think that this will be the best solution. Here is a good [Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/icloud-programming-ios-intro-tutorial/) for getting into iCloud.